# how to switch between charge modes in Lenovo ideapad c340-14IWL

Tags: lenovo, laptop, battery, charging

i have Lenovo ideapad c340-14IWL and Ubuntu 20.04 installed.
How to switch between charge modes.

> fast charge | normal | conservation mode (<60%)

for Windows we have "lenovo vantage". on Ubuntu I could only find how to switch between normal and conservation mode.

turn conservation mode mode on:

```
echo  -n  "1" | sudo tee /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode > /dev/null
```

to turn off use same command but replace "1" to "0":

```
echo  -n  "0" | sudo tee /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode > /dev/null
```

or manually edit file .../conservation_mode

in this folder (...VPC2004:00/) i found "F toggle" file contains "0" or "1".  changing it can toggle function F keys (F1-F12).
but can't find any fast-charge settings

Comment: Did you finally found it?